# HTML Input Button JS onClick

Tags: javascript, html, button, input

I'm trying to execute a script only when the button is pressed, my problem is that the script is being executed every time I refresh or enter in the page...

My JS function:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("addcarrinho").onclick = function ()
    {
        alert("<?PHP add_prod_carrinho(get_produto(@$_GET['id'])[0][id_produto]); ?>");
    };
</script>
```

This function executes every single time I enter the page, can someone explain me why?

This was my first function:

```
<script>
    function add_carrinho()
    {
        alert("<?PHP add_prod_carrinho(get_produto(@$_GET['id'])[0][id_produto]); ?>");
    };
</script>
```

Also not working.

This is the function that the script executes:

```
function add_prod_carrinho($prod_id)
{
    global $connection;

    $query = "INSERT INTO carrinho (id_cliente, id_produto) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['user_id']."', '".$prod_id."');";

    if(!$connection->query($query))
    {
        echo 'Houve um erro ao adicionar o produto ao carrinho.';
    }
}
```

This is the full page for this code:

```
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
.tg .tg-yw4l{vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-yw42{text-align:left; vertical-align:top;}
</style>

<script>
    document.getElementById("addcarrinho").onclick = function ()
    {
        alert("<?PHP add_prod_carrinho(get_produto(@$_GET['id'])[0][id_produto]); ?>");
    };
</script>
                    <!-- Begin Post -->
                    <div class="content_product">
                        <h2>Produtos - <?php echo get_produto(@$_GET['id'])[0][nome]; ?><span class="title-bottom">&nbsp;</span></h2>
                        <?php
                                echo '<table class="tg">
                                      <tr>
                                        <th class="tg-yw4l"><img src="css/images/product-img1.jpg" alt="Imagem de '.get_produto(@$_GET['id'])[0][nome].'" /></th>
                                        <th class="tg-yw42">
                                            '.get_produto(@$_GET['id'])[0][nome].'
                                            </br>
                                            '.get_produto(@$_GET['id'])[0][descricao_breve].'
                                            </br>
                                            </br>
                                            <span>Preço s/iva: </span>'.get_produto(@$_GET['id'])[0][preco_sem_iva].'<span>€</span>
                                            </br>
                                            <span>Preço c/iva: </span>'.get_produto(@$_GET['id'])[0][preco_com_iva].'<span>€</span>
                                            </br>
                                            </br>
                                            '.get_produto(@$_GET['id'])[0][id_produto].'
                                            <input id="addcarrinho" type="button" value="Adicionar ao carrinho" onclick="add_carrinho()"/>
                                        </th>
                                      </tr>
                                    </table>
                                            </br>
                                            '.get_produto(@$_GET['id'])[0][descricao].'';
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Post -->
```

I'm using containers, soo there's no body or head tag on this page...

Can someone help me?

Thanks

EDIT: Thanks to @vogomatix for helping me out.
Solution:

```
<script>
  $(".addcarrinho").click( function() {
    $.ajax({
       url: "http://your_server/add_prod.php",
       data: { id: your_id }
    })
  })
</script>
```

Comment: PHP is run on the server when building your page, javaScript is run on the client, which is why your PHP is being run every time the page is generated on the server. `add_prod_carrinho` is a PHP function.

Comment: How can I run that function only when the javascript function is executed? That's the only reference to that function that I have on the project, it should only be running only when the script runs as well...

Comment: The search term you're looking for is "AJAX".

Comment: Your onClick method should generate a request to the server, which in turn calls your PHP function.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol thanks, I'm going to try with AJAX.

Comment: @vogomatix but should only generate when clicked, right?

Comment: See the answer I wrote below, which gives you a starting point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

1. a script which processes the request from the page, containing the method `add_prod_carrihno` and which receives the parameters for the method. Lets call this one `add_prod.php`.
2. a script which generates the page e.g. index.php

In index.php, you have your *onClick* method which generates a request to call `http://your_server/add_prod.php?id=1234`, where 1234 is the id you want to insert.

```javascript
\\ load jQuery here....

<script>
  $(".addcarrinho").click( function() {
    $.ajax({
       url: "http://your_server/add_prod.php",
       data: { id: your_id }
    })
  })
</script>
```